# What algorithm is used for converting an ArrayList<T> to a LinkedHashSet<T> in JRE

Tags: java, algorithm, hashmap, set, linkedhashset

I wanted to get a `list` of unique elements from a `list` with duplicate elements and the order of elements occurring in the list should be maintained.

To achieve this, I could have written an algorithm like:

```
private ArrayList<T> getUnique(ArrayList<T> list)
{
    // maintain a hashmap of numbers and a uniqueList to be returned(ArrayList<T>)
    // Add element in result list and the hashmap if the element isn't already present in the hashmap, else just add in the hashmap

    HashMap<T, Boolean> map = new HashMap<>();
    ArrayList<T> uniqueList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (T t: list)
    {
        if (map.get(t) == null)
        {
            // t wasn't present so, adding them in map as well as in the list
            map.put(t, true);
            uniqueList.add(t);
        }
    }
    return uniqueList;
}
```

This algorithm will take `O(n)` time with `O(n)` extra space (for HashMap).

Or simply, I could have used the below syntax:

```
Set<T> set = new LinkedHashSet<>(list);
```

The above syntax in Java is used for getting a `set` of unique elements from `list` with occurrence order of elements same as that of `list`.
Then convert this set in a list. (`ArrayList<T> uniqueList = new ArrayList<>(set);`)

I am assuming the time complexity here is also `O(n)`. I wanted to know what algorithm Java uses for it.

I see the class is named LinkedHashSet, so I thought that they might be using some `LinkedList` concepts for achieving this, So I looked into the source code, and found these stuff:

1. In `LinkedHashSet.java`, the constructor looks like:

`143:   public LinkedHashSet(Collection<? extends T> c)
 144:   {
 145:     super(c);
 146:   }`

[here](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/LinkedHashSet-source.html) is the source.

2. So, I looked at the parent class constructor i.e. `HashSet`, I found:

`public HashSet(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    map = new HashMap<>(Math.max((int) (c.size()/.75f) + 1, 16));
    addAll(c);
}`

3. Next, I searched for `addAll` method, I found it in `AbstractCollection` class(which is the grandparent of `HashSet` class), the definition of the function is:

`public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
        boolean modified = false;
        for (E e : c)
            if (add(e))
                modified = true;
        return modified;
    }`

This is calling `add` which is like:

`public boolean add(E e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }`

[here](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#L251).

I couldn't understand this. What algorithm do they use for this task?

Comment: Where is your source/version for LinkedHashSet.java? I see different content with the line number given in https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedHashSet.java.

Comment: @samabcde [this](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/LinkedHashSet-source.html)

Comment: @samabcde - The line numbers don't matter.  This aspect of the code is the same for multiple versions.  (And besides, Java 7 is **way out of date**.)

Comment: `add` is a polymorphic method (all methods are in Java). Take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605669/what-is-polymorphic-method-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### For someone looking for the whole story

Base on the source code of [LinkedHashSet](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/LinkedHashSet-source.html), [HashSet](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/HashSet-source.html), [LinkedHashMap](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/util/LinkedHashMap-source.html).
When constructing a `LinkedHashSet` which extends `HashSet` with other collection(LinkedHashSet.java line 143),

```
public LinkedHashSet(Collection<? extends T> c)  
{  
  super(c);  
}
```

Which will call (HashSet.java line 136):

```
public HashSet(Collection<? extends T> c)
{
  this(Math.max(2 * c.size(), HashMap.DEFAULT_CAPACITY));
  addAll(c);
}
```

and then call (HashSet.java line 122):

```
public HashSet(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor)
{
  map = init(initialCapacity, loadFactor);
}
```

Since the `init` method is overrided in `LinkedHashSet`

```
HashMap<T, String> init(int capacity, float load)
{
 return new LinkedHashMap<T, String>(capacity, load);
}
```

The backing `map` is a `LinkedHashMap`.

According to java doc of [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

> This class provides all of the optional Map operations, and permits null elements. Like HashMap, it provides **constant-time performance** for the basic operations (add, contains and remove), assuming the hash function disperses elements properly among the buckets. Performance is likely to be just slightly below that of HashMap, due to the added expense of maintaining the linked list, with one exception: Iteration over the collection-views of a LinkedHashMap requires time proportional to the size of the map, regardless of its capacity. Iteration over a HashMap is likely to be more expensive, requiring time proportional to its capacity.

And the `add` method of `HashSet` is

```
public boolean add(E e) {
   return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
}
```

Hence the average time complexity is O(n) for the construction.
For the algorithm, I think you can read the code of LinkedHashMap for details.
Further reading [How is the internal implementation of LinkedHashMap different from HashMap implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19738977/how-is-the-internal-implementation-of-linkedhashmap-different-from-hashmap-imple), [HashSet vs LinkedHashSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080612/hashset-vs-linkedhashset?rq=1)

Comment: Yes: "requires editing" means that anybody can fix the question by making it answerable. Here, the OP, the person asking the question needs to add information. Then you should rather look for some sort of close reason. Beyond that: I appreciate the quick and friendly comeback!

Answer (score 3):

To answer your confusion, the `add` method is overridden in `HashSet` as follows:

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
}
```

Note that `LinkedHashSet` extends `HashSet` extends `AbstractSet` extends `AbstractCollection`.

---

In summary, the algorithm used is:

```
    for (E e : c)
        add(e);
```

which is `O(N)` for a `LinkedHashSet` since the average complexity of `add` for `LinkedHashSet` is `O(1)`.

Comment: yes, this add method is defined in `HashSet` class, but constructor in the HashSet class is calling the `addAll` method which isn't present in HashSet, I found it in `AbstractCollection` class which is grandparent of HashSet class. So, how can a grandparent's method call child class method?

Comment: inheritance.  the child class inherits the grandparent's methods

Comment: `AddAll` is in `AbstractCollection`.  That's the method that the `LinkedHashSet` constructor is calling.   So the short answer is (as Jason says) "inheritance".

Comment: @Jason Yes you are right, but I asked `how can a grandparent's method call child class method?` Inheritance will give this capability to the child class. Also, I see the signature of `AbstractCollection` as: `public abstract class AbstractCollection<E> implements Collection<E>` it doesn't inherit.

Comment: @AmitUpadhyay - Inheritance gives the "capability" to call (visible) methods declared in **all** superclasses.  The parent, the grand parent ... all the way to `java.lang.Object`.  ( Provided that the method hasn't be overridden in an intermediate class. )  You probably been to review the basics of inheritance in Java, because this is pretty fundamental.

Comment: @AmitUpadhyay It is late binding and polymorphism

Comment: @StephenC , thanks, I know what you have clarified above, but I missed out the comment written there `<p>Note that this implementation will throw an
     * <tt>UnsupportedOperationException</tt> unless <tt>add</tt> is
     * overridden (assuming the specified collection is non-empty).` I now got it. Also, what I was asking is how can child method have scope in parent class?.[this](https://ideone.com/oOs1Ht). thanks!

Answer (score 2):

this is `LinkedHashSet` constructor :

```
public LinkedHashSet(Collection<? extends E> c) {
        super(Math.max(2*c.size(), 11), .75f, true);
        addAll(c);
    }
```

this is addAll function from `java.util.AbstractCollection`:

```
public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c) {
        boolean modified = false;
        for (E e : c)
            if (add(e))
                modified = true;
        return modified;
    }
```

this is add function from `java.util.HashSet`:

```
public boolean add(E e) {
        return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
    }
```

easy-peasy if you use Intellij to find the source of the function.